# Import and export a list of SparseArrays efficiently?

Tags: performance-tuning, export, import, files-and-directories, sparse-arrays

I have a list of integers `dims` and a list of `SparseArray`s `bdrs` (representing a [chain complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex) $\mathbb{Z}^{d_0}\overset{\partial_1}{\leftarrow}\mathbb{Z}^{d_1}\overset{\partial_2}{\leftarrow}\mathbb{Z}^{d_2}\leftarrow\ldots$).

I wish to import/export such data from/to a `file.txt` (each line should be a matrix entry). For instance, the data
$$\mathbb{Z}^{2}\xleftarrow{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}5&0&0\\0&6&7\end{smallmatrix}\right]} \mathbb{Z}^{3}\xleftarrow{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&8&0&0\\9&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&-2\end{smallmatrix}\right]}\mathbb{Z}^{4}$$
corresponds to a file

```
2 3 4

1 1 5
2 2 6
2 3 7

1 2 8
2 1 9
3 3 -1
3 4 -2
```

and $$
\mathbb{Z}^{7}\xleftarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}^{0}\xleftarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}^{5}
\xleftarrow{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\\end{smallmatrix}\right]} 
\mathbb{Z}^{2}\xleftarrow{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&15\\21&0&0&0\\\end{smallmatrix}\right]} \mathbb{Z}^{4}$$
corresponds to a file

```
7 0 5 2 4




1 4 14
2 1 21
```

My solution is:

```
chcxIn[file_]:= Module[{s,dims,bdrs={},k=1,i=1}, s=Import["/home/"<>file,"List"]; 
   s=Map[If[#=="",{},ImportString[#,"Table"][[1]]]&,s];   dims=s[[1]];   s=ParallelMap[If[#=={},{},#[[;;2]]->#[[3]]]&,s[[3;;]],{1}]; 
   Do[ If[s[[j]]=={}, AppendTo[bdrs,SparseArray[s[[i;;j-1]], dims[[k;;k+1]]]]; k+=1; i=j+1;],{j,Length@s}];   Return@{bdrs,dims}]; 
chcxOut[bdrs_,dims_,file_]:= Export["/home/"<>file, {StringReplace[ ToString@dims, {"{"->"","}"->"",","->""}],""}~Join~
   Flatten[Table[ArrayRules[b][[;; -2]]~Join~{""} /.({u_,v_}->w_):>(ToString[u]<>" "<>ToString[v]<>" "<>ToString[w]), {b,bdrs}],1]~Join~{""}, "List"];
```

However, this is hopelessly inefficient (time and memory wise). For 50MB of data, `chcxOut` needs 65 seconds and 700MB of RAM. This seems excessive. I wish to deal with files of size 10GB. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

---

Edit: With the help of @HenrikSchumacher, here is an improvement.

```
chcxIn[fileName_] := Module[{s=OpenRead[fileName],r(*read*), l(*line*), dims,bdrs={},k=0,e={}}, 
   dims=ImportString[Read[s,String],"Table"][[1]];  
   r:=Read[s,Record,NullRecords->True]; Monitor[If[s=!=$Failed, While[l=!=EndOfFile, l=r;   
   Which[l=="0", , l=="", k+=1; AppendTo[bdrs,SparseArray[e,dims[[k;;k+1]]]]; e={}, True, 
   l=ImportString[l,"Table"][[1]]; AppendTo[e,l[[1;;2]]->l[[3]]]]; ]], k];  Close[s]; {bdrs,dims}]; 
chcxOut[bdrs_,dims_,fileName_] := Module[{f=OpenWrite[fileName], w(*write*)}, 
   w=WriteString[f,ExportString[#,"Table"]]&; w@{dims}; WriteString[f,"\n\n"]; 
   Monitor[ Do[ If[Times@@dims[[k;;k+1]]==0 || bdrs[[k]]["Density"]==0, w@{0}, 
      w@Join[bdrs[[k]]["NonzeroPositions"],Partition[bdrs[[k]]["NonzeroValues"], 1], 2]];   
     WriteString[f,"\n\n"],{k,Length@bdrs}],k];     Close[f];];
```

For a 2MB file, the time and memory performance is:
`Export` 0.1sec 4MB, `Import` 0.2sec 8MB, `chcxOut` 1.1sec 12MB, `chcxIn` 265sec 9MB. As we can see, importing from my custom format is still *much* slower. Hopefully, there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Use a sparse matrix format like `MAT`, `MTX`, or `"HarwellBoeing"`. `MAT` is a binary format and should produce the smallest files.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher These files will also be read in Python, C++, SageMath, GAP, so I'd like to stick to this format. Also, my data is a *sequence* of matrices, not just one.

Comment: Even more a reason to use a standard format. Otherwise you will have to reimplement import/export in all these languages. Btw.: `MAT` _can_ handle sequences of matrices.

Comment: And all aforementioned programs support this format? Hmm, give me a bit of time to try import/export using .mat.

Comment: Yes, have a look. I am pretty sure that there must be APIs for Python (alone for migration reasons from MATLAB to SciPy) and C++. SageMath has MAT support through SciPy, too. So if you call GAP from SageMath, this should also be covered.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I've tried `Export["file.mat",bdrs]`, but obtain the error `... cannot be exported to the MAT format.`. Could you please show me how my problem can be solved? (you can reply as an answer, not comment)

Comment: Ah, I just tried it myself and realized that _Mathematica_ must store sparse matrices as dense matrices when experoting to `"MAT"` format. Super annoying. I wrote a hand-code, not very optimized solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work.

```
dims = Prepend[(Dimensions /@ bndrs)[[All, 2]], Dimensions[bndrs[[1]]][[1]]];
file = OpenWrite["a.txt"];
WriteString[file, ExportString[{dims}, "Table"]];
Do[
  WriteString[file, "\n\n"];
  WriteString[
   file,
   ExportString[
    Join[A["NonzeroPositions"], Partition[A["NonzeroValues"], 1], 2],
    "Table"
    ]],
  {A, bndrs}];
Close[file]
```

The result is a human-readible file, so it is not really super compressed.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work when some of the matrices have height or width 0.

Comment: Then you have to write an ecxeption for that case...